# Keycloak use IdP display name instead of alias in templates

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

The Identity Provider Link email template uses the "alias" of an identity provider (`identityProviderAlias`) as one of the variables into the email body. I'd prefer to use the IdP's "display name".

I tried `identityProviderDisplayName`, but that printed `null`.

My IdP alias is something like "company-prod-sso", and the display name is "Company SSO"

**Update:**

I've now also tried to use the `identityProviderContext` as follows:
`identityProviderContext.getIdpConfig().getAlias()` returns the same thing as `identityProviderAlias` (except not capitalized). `identityProviderContext.getIdpConfig().getDisplayName()` returns `null`. Using it like this:

```
${kcSanitize(msg("identityProviderLinkBodyHtml", identityProviderContext.getIdpConfig().getDisplayName(), realmName, identityProviderContext.username, link, linkExpiration, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
```

Thanks to @jan-garaj for pointing to the code that adds the `alias` and `brokerContext` variables to the template attributes.

**Second Update:**
Ok, apparently the social providers (which I was using in my test environment) don't have display names. The above approach does work when a display name is defined. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brokerContext (available as `identityProviderContext` in the theme) has a path to the display name, but the display name is optional for some providers, and just not available on others (GitHub social provider, for example).

I've updated the identity-provider-link.ftl by replacing the original parameter `identityProviderAlias` to:

```
identityProviderContext.getIdpConfig().getDisplayName()!identityProviderAlias
```

That will use the display name in the body, if available. Otherwise it defaults to the original alias parameter.

I also created an enhancement request to make the display name available to the email subject, which doesn't use a template. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16380

Answer (score 1):

That attribute is not available on the template level - it is not passed there. See the source code: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java#L151

Comment: This answer wasn't completely correct, but the source code in the link was VERY helpful in finding a solution. Thanks, Jan!